# apache 403 Forbidden error which should work but not

Tags: apache

It's my first time to use apache server, I was trying to find the answer but failed at last, could anyone please help with this issue ? Following is the information which may be impacted.

Error message when I type http://[hostname]/index.php

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at [hostname] Port 80
```

OS information:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

httpd.conf information
$ cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (part of http.conf)

```
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir disabled
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html.var index.html index.htm

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

HostnameLookups Off

Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/">
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/">
 #Options FollowSymLinks
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
 AllowOverride None
 Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess

```
$ cat .htaccess
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

config of selinux:

```
sudo cat /etc/selinux/config
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.

#SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUX=disabled

# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Comment: How about  "ls -l /var/www"

Comment: $ ls -l /var/www
total 24  
drwxrwsr-x.  2 root www 4096 Aug  2 08:02 cgi-bin
drwxrwsr-x.  3 root www 4096 Dec 21 00:57 error
drwxrwsr--.  5 root www 4096 Dec 24 12:16 html
drwxrwsr-x.  3 root www 4096 Dec 21 00:57 icons
drwxrwsr-x. 14 root www 4096 Dec 21 00:57 manual
    drwxrwsr-x.  2 root www 4096 Dec 23 03:31 usage

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very clear how to format the comments.

Comment: I don't see a document root? Try adding DocumentRoot /var/www or /var/www/html and a block for that directory.

Comment: Yeah, however, if I create a index.html in /var/www/html/ . It works well, I'm really boring about it.

Comment: Hi， JAL， as far as I know, if the root cause is from DocumentRoot, it  shouldn't worked if I created a index.html in it. Anyway, appreciated your help, please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: that's correct. I didn't see that info but yes, if any file works then the webserver and permissions are set up mostly okay...

Comment: I find the root cause, really happy about that, it's from httpd wiki, post quick link here [http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied] , what I have done   is to grant the permission to the whole path iteratelly of /var/www/html/, that is, `cd /var/www/`  `sudo chmod +x html/`  `cd ..` `sudo chmod +x www` `cd ..`  `sudo chmod +x var/` , finally, thank you very much JAL, merry Christmas！

Comment: Wonderful, glad it's working! Merry Christmas to you as well @jjs